# Bidirectional range slider with colors for both directions

Tags: javascript, html, css, slider, bidirectional

totally newbie with css, html and js scripting here. I'm basically googling for the things I want to implement and modify existing code. I'm building a web interface to control a couple of motors and I'm using range sliders to control their direction and speed (slide to the right --> move to right, etc. Also the further the slider the faster the motors move). My current setup is the following

```js
function gripBidirectional() {
  var delayInMilliseconds = 250;

  setTimeout(function() {
    var bcw = document.getElementById('bcw').value;
   var posBcw = Math.abs(bcw);
    if(posBcw < 40){
     document.getElementById('bcw').value = 0
     var rot = 0 << 10 | 0 ;
     var rotstr = '@'+ rot.toString(16);
     //connection.send(rotstr);
    }
    if(bcw < 0 ){
   //left
   var rot = posBcw << 10 | 1 ;
   var rotstr = '^'+ rot.toString(16);
   //connection.send(rotstr);
    } else {
     // right
     var rot = posBcw << 10 | 0 ;
     var rotstr = '@'+ rot.toString(16);
     //connection.send(rotstr);
    }
  }, delayInMilliseconds);
}
```

```css
:root{
  --myTrackColor: rgb(0,201,255);
  --myThumbColor: rgb(152,162,174);
}

.slider {
    -webkit-appearance: none;
    -webkit-transition: .2s;
    transition: opacity .2s;
    width: 380px; /* Height of the scrollbar */
    height: 8px; /* Height of the scrollbar */
    border-radius: 5px;   /* This is the radius for the scroll bar */
    background: rgb(190,200,210); /* If height too big, then you need this to have the same color in the scrollbar */
    outline: none;
    opacity: 0.7;
}

.slider:hover {
  opacity: 1;
}

.slider::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  appearance: none;
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--myThumbColor); /* This is color for the circle */
  cursor: pointer;
}

.slider::-moz-range-thumb {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border: solid;
  border-width: thin;
  border-color: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background: var(--myThumbColor); /* This is color for the circle */
  cursor: pointer;
}

/* The following only affects the range input in FF */
input[type="range"]::-moz-range-progress {
  background-color: var(--myTrackColor);
  height: 8px; /* Height of the scrollbar */
  border-radius: 5px;   /* This is the radius for the scroll bar */
}

input[type="range"]::-moz-range-track {
  background-color: white;
  height: 8px; /* Height of the scrollbar */
  border-radius: 5px;   /* This is the radius for the scroll bar */
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Robotic Arm Control Panel</title>
    <link href='main.css' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <meta content='width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, user-scalable=0' name='viewport'>
    <script src="https://stacksnippets.net/js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>

<div>
  <input class="slider" style="margin-top:40px" id="bcw" type="range" min="-255" max="255"  step="1" oninput="gripBidirectional();" value="0">
</div>

<table>
  <tr>
    <td style="padding-left: 0px; text-align: left">LEFT </td>
    <td style="padding-left: 300px; text-align: right">RIGHT </td>
  </tr>
</table>

</body>
</html>
```

Currently the left area is filled up with the blue color that indicates progress, but what I want to achieve is that the slider is initiated at the null position with the neutral grey background for both directions. Then as I slide it to the left or right it gets filled up with the background blue color.

thanks in advance